# Which unistd.h is being included? (c++)

Tags: c++, include, libraries, unistd.h

I was exploring the libraries for educational purposes and came across the file os_defines.h , which on my MacBoook is located in usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits . There I find `#include <unistd.h>`, so I did a quick finder search for that file and came up with no less than 7 files of that name! The files are not copies, and NONE of them are located in the same folder as os_defines.h - so which file exactly is being included?

I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious, but I am a wee rookie, and if anyone can shine me a light it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible cross dupe: [Where does gcc keep its built-in include directory paths](http://serverfault.com/questions/147590/where-does-gcc-keep-its-built-in-include-directory-paths),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we cannot mark duplicates across SE sites (and I couldn't find one quickly at Stack Overflow), and assuming you are using GCC I'll restate the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/147599/157776) here:

> > The preprocessor can tell you what it uses
> >
> > cpp -x c++ -v
> >
> > ...
> >
> > ```
> >    #include "..." search starts here:
> >    #include <...> search starts here:
> >     /usr/include/c++/4.4
> >     /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu
> >     /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
> >     /usr/local/include
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include
> >     /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include-fixed
> >     /usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
> >     /usr/include
> >    End of search list.
> > ```

You can add directories to the search path by setting the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and/or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variiables

Comment: @CameronSnell You may consider to accept that answer then.